# Techniques for loading page with several thumbnail images (laravel 5.3)

Tags: javascript, css, json, ajax, http

I have a web site with a section with several small images (about 24) per page. When I visit the page I can see the page being enlarged, text is shown before the associated image and etc. That's not a problem for me, because I know that the web was designed to work this way so that web site visitors could see something before the page is fully loaded. The problem is that, today, people are fighting against this principle to achieve beauty, hiding sections of the page until it is completely loaded is common if not required. I cannot fight this (If I could I would). When I show my website to some developer I can see that he completely embranced this idea of beauty in favor of "old principles".

I never really tried to design a page that has a "smart image loading" so I don't know where to start and that's why I'm here. If you can list me some techniques, plugin and etc that can be used  to perform progressive image loads in pages would be helpful.

My page is being loaded by simply returning a view with all the images. I assume that to achieve the smart image loading I will have to get the images and associanted text by returning json from the controller, is that correct? If so, I will have to make a major change in my system. I briefly saw a technique that it sets all the images on the page to an animated gif image and then when the data is fetch from the server (using ajax/json) it substitutes the src atribute of the image, is that a good technique. Again, what the best tecniques are?

Comment: You might want to retag your questoin with `html`, `css`, `javascript`. If you're using Laravel and vuejs you could consider using vuejs's features to conditionally render images once they've been loaded.

Comment: See adam wathan's method also for stopping the page from enlarging for an image while it's still loading: https://youtu.be/ktj_GR1LvFw?t=588

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and css to display a loading animation before the page completely loads

Tutorial: http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/

Working example : http://smallenvelop.com/demo/simple-pre-loader/

Big Company's website who uses loading animation : https://club.ubisoft.com/

Just a warning: website who uses this technique will look slower, user might even leave the website before the page loads, I personally think the default behaviour of showing text first is still the best.